# Css - Width / Height 100% without dynamic amount of pixels

Tags: css, responsive-design, width

How to set the width of an element to take 100% the **width** of its parent minus an unknown **width** of sibling element.

#### index.html

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="sidemenu">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="contant">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

#### style.css

```
.main
{
  width: 100vw;
}

.sidemenu
{
  width: X; /* this value is dymanic, it may change in runtime using JS */
}

.contant
{
  width: ???; /* what do I put here? */
}
```

If the side-menu width was fixed I could of use `calc(100% - X)`, but since the width is dynamic, how can I set the width to take the remaining width of the parent?
Can I achieve this using Css only (without JavaScript)?

Comment: just wondering , `width: auto;` not working?

Comment: @Ylama - Nop, I wish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `flexbox` so there's no need to assign a specific width to the `content` area

e.g.

```
.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.content { flex: 1; margin-left: 1rem; }
```

> [Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/fcalderan/pen/WMwVPy)

Comment: @GilEpshtain Only display: flex is enough, otherwise its flex-direction: column not columns and flex-wrap: nowrap is by default.

Comment: @VXp by default flex-direction is set to row.

Comment: I'm talking about flex-wrap.

Comment: @VXp please re-insert the flex-direction, thank you.

Comment: What is it that you don't understand? There's no flex-direction: columns and using flex-direction: column is not the desired result.

Comment: @VXp https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction OP wants to columns, not 2 rows.

Comment: Again, what is it that you don't understand?... Clearly OP doesn't want that, where do you see two rows? There's only one row, by default, with display flex and no additional properties...The problem is already solved, I just removed the unnecessary lines of code. Open your link, remove both lines of code, do you see any difference? No, because flex-wrap: nowrap is by default and there is no flex-direction: columns with an s! And if you used flex-direction: column that wouldn't be the desired result since he want to have both on the same line...

Comment: @VXp - If an answerer rolls back your edits and asks you to stop, please listen to them. Don't try to force your own interpretation on someone else's answer. If you want to write your own answer, feel free to do so.

Comment: @GilEpshtain Just remember that you only need `display: flex` on the parent and `flex: 1` on one of the children, which will then fill the horizontal space. You don't need additional properties like flex-direction: column and flex-wrap: nowrap (already by default), but author of this answer just doesn't understand that. Codepen only works because of the typo "columns" which is not a valid flex value so it's not taken into account, and using column is not what you were after.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but this could also be done using css variables.

```
:root {
  --dynamic-width: X;
}
.content {
  width: CALC(100% - var(--dynamic-width));
}
```

See: https://jsfiddle.net/wzget15m/

Answer (score -1):

Use `display: flex` in the main container:

```
    .main {
        display: flex;
    } 
    .sidemenu {
        width: X;
    } 
    .contant {
        width: 100%; /* what do I put here? */ 
    }
```

Comment: This will not work, the content will simply overflow out of the screen

Comment: This happend for width: 100vw; of div.main, I deleted this of the code.

Answer (score -1):

the method you might look for is only possible using js otherwise you can't get the width of the element to calculate it with another.

Comment: This wont solve the problem, as I mentioned in the question - the size of the sizebar is dynamic, therefore I can't use fixed values like 12px

Comment: OP doesn't know in advance how much to subtract from 100%.